# Can a Body Dent on Mac book pro be repaired?

Tags: hardware

I have a Mac book pro 15 inch mid 2010 & there is a small dent between the touch pad & space bar as i dropped a metal ball by accident however it does not effect the performance of my Laptop at all, can it be repaired ? It does't look good...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the Apple Store.  They will give you a quote to replace the housing.  You'll have to bring it to a body shop to find out if it can be repaired!